# Dynamics CRM Tables : The purpose of these security tables:- SystemUserPrincipals, PrincipalEntityMap, PrincipalAttributeAccessMap?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

i want to know the purpose of these dynamics CRM tables as i am trying to understand the internals of the dynamics CRM security model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a great article that's going to help you to understand how the security model works:

[CRM Security Model Internals](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2007/04/05/crm-security-model-internals/)

> In this post I’ll describe some of the CRM Security Model internals. I’ll describe how roles and privileges are used under the covers, how security is enforced for different operations, and some of the internal structures that make it possible.